# Laravel Eloquent : Ignore null values on an return

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to modify my eloquent query to get only json value where family.equipment is different than null.

Here is my request:

```
$data = Ov::with([
    'name',
    'family.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    },
    'family.device.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    }
])->distinct()->get();
```

And the actual result:

Return :

```
[
  {
    "name": [
      {
        "label": "LIC",
        "value": "@ew9Ddededezdzec"
      }
    ],
    "family": [
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "equipment": null,
        "device": []
      },
      {
        "name": "test2",
        "equipment": null,
        "device": []
      },
      {
        "name": "test3",
        "equipment": {
            'name': "test",
        }
        "device": []
      },
    ]
  },...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `whereNotNull`

```
$data = Ov::with([
    'name',
    'family.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    },
    'family.device.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->whereNotNull('family.device.id_equipment')->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    }
])->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: I get an SQL error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'equipment' in 'where clause' ``

Comment: equipment is a column name?

Comment: ca you provide the tables for this query?

Comment: No, it's a name of a table (with relationship)

Comment: ca you provide the tables for this query and the relationships??

Comment: It's difficult to provide the tables because the database is complicated. Just few words: Ov is a table with has many name, ov has many family, family has an equipment, family has many devices which have an equipment. Equipment is a table with multiple columns.

Comment: so you need to return all devices that have the id_equipment null,yes?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a `filter` method call.

```
$data = Ov::with([
    'name',
    'family.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    },
    'family.device.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    }
])->distinct()->filter()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `has` and `whereHas`. See [Docs - querying-relationship-existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
Ov::has('family.equipment')-> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`has`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method to eliminate null equipment and then perform a join:

```
$data = Ov::has('families.equipments')->with([
    'name',
    'family.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    },
    'family.device.equipment' => function ($query) use ($model) {
        $query->where('model', 'like', $model)->orWhere('baseModel', 'like', $model);
    }
])->distinct()->get();
```